# Can I use kwargs to pass this part of the function?

Tags: python

I am using this autoclean function in the datacleaner library in python.
It does 3 things,
(1)impute missing values with mode (Categorical)
(2) impute missing values with median (continuous)
(3) and then does label encoding

I want the function to 'skip' encoding. I know there is a kwarg in the function that I can use.
How should I go about it?

```
 from datacleaner import autoclean
  cdf= autoclean(df, encoder=True, encoder_kwargs=None)
```

This is the error message(which also means the underlying code):

```
     90         if str(input_dataframe[column].values.dtype) == 'object':
     91             if encoder is not None:
---> 92                 column_encoder = encoder(**encoder_kwargs).fit(input_dataframe[column].values)
     93             else:
     94                 column_encoder = LabelEncoder().fit(input_dataframe[column].values)
```

Comment: "This is the error message" - this is not an error message. Please post the full traceback (starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):`)

Answer (score 0):

Python’s `**` notation as a prefix expects a dictionary to unpack as kwargs, so it makes sense that it errors when given `None` as a value.

Try setting `encoder_kwargs={}` in your call instead, that should fix the immediate error. I don’t know if that will “skip” encoding like you wanted, though.